# How do I read .xls file into a long string with Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, xls

How can I use Python to read .xls file into a long string? I have thousands of files and want to replace '.' with ',' within each of them.

Comment: Did you try just opening and reading the file?

Comment: yeah I did; doesn't work.

Comment: Then how do you expect it to be represented as "a long string"?

Comment: Did you try to use library openpyxl for instance ? You can easily read content of Excel cells, manipulate it, then (over)write a workbook...

Comment: @LaurentH. How is that "reading it into a long string"?

Answer (score 0):

> yeah I did; doesn't work.

Hmmm, it works for me

```
import xlrd #for reading
import xlwt #for writing

def exceledit(path):
    #Open the book:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

    #Create new book
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

    #Open sheet:
    for i in range(0, len(wb.sheet_names())):
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(i)
        sh_name = wb.sheet_names()[i]
        print(sh_name)

        #Create new sheet
        sheet = book.add_sheet(sh_name)

        #Read row:
        for k in range(0, sh.nrows):
            row = sh.row_values(k)

            #Replace '.' with ',' in cell
            for j in range(0, len(row)):
                row[j] = str(row[j]).replace(".",",")

                # Write row:
                sheet.write(k,j,row[j])

    #Save new book            
    book.save(path[:-4] + "_edited.xls")

exceledit('D:/files/myexcelfile.xls')
```

Could you give your code?